# Angular - Display Todo result from API call

Tags: angularjs

I am learning with a simple Todo angular app. A user has to type the username and display the list of todos from the API get call. When I keep the API call outside getTodo function call and directly enable 2-way binding with todos scope variable, I am able to display the todos. However inside the getTodo function call, on success return from API call, todos scope variable doesn't remain in Angular context.

```html
Main Todo List
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <form name="form1">
    <p>Enter Username:<input name="username" type="text" ng-model="username"  ng-minlength='4' required/>
         <span ng-show="form1.username.$error.minlength">Username has to be atleast 4 chars</span></p>
        <div ng-messages="form1.username.$error">
            <div ng-message="required" ng-style={color:'purple'}> get todos for test user. type your username to get and add your todos</div>
        </div>
        <div ng-model="todos"> 
            <!--<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="getTodo()">Get Todo</a>-->
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="getTodo()">Get Todo</button>
            <h3>Todos</h3>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                    {{ todo.todo }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```js
// MODULE
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp',['ngRoute']);

angularApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/MainTodo.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/edittodo', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/EditTodo.html',
        controller: 'editController'
    })
});

angularApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$location', '$log', '$http', 
    function ($scope, $location, $log, $http) {
    //$log.info($location.path());
    $scope.username = "test";
    $scope.todos = {};
    var uname = $scope.username;
    var getApiPath = '/api/todos/' + uname;
    $scope.getTodo = function() {
        $http.get(getApiPath)
        .success(function (result) {
            $scope.todos = result;
            console.log(result);
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            console.log(data);

        }); 
    };

}]);

angularApp.controller('editController', ['$scope', '$location', '$log', function ($scope, $location, $log) {
    //$log.info($location.path());
}]);
```

Comment: does $scope.username  return a value ? 
i believe your function is called, but in code you should use 
$scope.$parent.username

Comment: Yes, I have added console.log (console.log(uname); after console.log(result); in the success promise and both are showing the data.

Comment: (2) [{…}, {…}]0: {_id: "5c240eb25928a60004ffb48b", username: "test", todo: "Biking", isDone: false, hasAttachment: false, …}1: {_id: "5c27fb3685734c000476bf22", username: "test", todo: "Texting", isDone: false, hasAttachment: false, …}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
app.js:29 test

Comment: so your method is called ? and it simply does not return any thing from the server ?

Comment: Data is being returned from the server.Issue is that $scope.todos should updated in the <ng-repeat> when getTodo() function is called.

Comment: let's say it is a server issue and data is not being returned. I have assigned todos manually and then data should display. I think it is more to do with how angular is manages scope context.  $scope.todos = [{"_id":"5c240eb25928a60004ffb48b","username":"test","todo":"Biking","isDone":false,"hasAttachment":false,"__v":0},
             {"_id":"5c27fb3685734c000476bf22","username":"test","todo":"Texting","isDone":false,"hasAttachment":false,"__v":0}];

Comment: ok so it's a binding issue.
did you try 
ng-model="{{todos}}" 

?

Comment: There can be only one `ng-model` attribute on an element. The `ng-model` directive does not work with `<a>` anchor elements.

Comment: Correct. When I change <a> to <button>, it is working. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't edit the code in the question to reflex the answer;  it only serves to make the question confusing to others who might be looking for a similar problem they may be experiencing, because they don't see the code in the broken state that matches the way their code looks, and the answers seem off because they seem to suggest changing things that don't look incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the extra `ng-model` attribute:

```
<p>Enter Username:<input name="username" type="text"
                         ng-model="username" ̶n̶g̶-̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶=̶"̶t̶o̶d̶o̶s̶"̶
                         ng-minlength='4' required/>
```

---

> The `ng-model` directive does not work with `<a>` anchor elements.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" ̶n̶g̶-̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶=̶"̶t̶o̶d̶o̶s̶"̶  ng-click="getTodo()">
  Get Todo
</a>
```

Comment: I have updated the template. The ng-model directive does not work with <a> anchor elements. Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with your  anchor tag. It was sending the app to the wrong page. Notice how angular removes the second forward slash from your url (/#/ will become /#). That´s why your page was not rendering right. I would also add it as ng-href.

Just change your href tag to this and it will work (add and / after the #):

```
<a ng-href="#/" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="todos" ng-click="getTodo()">Get Todo</a>
```